# Изображения в аттечменте php

Tags: php, email, sendmail, base64, gmail

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$vk = $_POST['vk'];
$whyWant = $_POST['whyWant'];
$whyYou = $_POST['whyYou'];
$markAndModel = $_POST['markAndModel'];
$answer = $_POST['answer'];

  $to = "test@test.test";
  $from = 'test@test.test';
  $subject = "Заполнена контактная форма с ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
  $message = "
  Имя пользователя: ".htmlspecialchars($name)."
  Телефон: ".htmlspecialchars($tel)."
  Возраст: ".htmlspecialchars($age)."
  ВК: ".htmlspecialchars($vk)."
  Ответ 1: ".htmlspecialchars($whyWant)."
  Ответ 2: ".htmlspecialchars($whyYou)."
  Марка-модель: ".htmlspecialchars($markAndModel)."
  Ответ 4: ".htmlspecialchars($answer);

  $boundary = md5(date('r', time()));
  $filesize = '';
  $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\r\n";
  $message="
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

    --$boundary
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

    $message";
  for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['photo_input']['name']);$i++) {
     if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo_input']['tmp_name'][$i])) {
         $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['photo_input']['tmp_name'][$i])));
         $filename = $_FILES['photo_input']['name'][$i];
         $filetype = $_FILES['photo_input']['type'][$i];
         $filesize += $_FILES['photo_input']['size'][$i];
         $message.="

        --$boundary
        Content-Type: \"$filetype\"; name=\"$filename\"
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
        Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"

        $attachment";
     }
   }
  $message.="
  --$boundary--";

  if ($filesize < 20000000) { 
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo 'vse ok';
  } else {
    echo 'Извините, письмо не отправлено. Размер всех файлов превышает 20 МБ.';
  }
```

На почту приходят все данные, фотографии в виде base64 строки. Как сделать чтобы они были как прикрепленные изображения? Спасибо!

Comment: Заменить \"$filetype\" на image/jpeg

Comment: Не работает: получаю расширение файла .pngContent-Transfer-Encoding-base64Content-Disposition-attachment

Comment: Не совсем ясно зачем  в `Content-Disposition` используется `filename=\"$filename\"`. Уберите этот параметр. Пробуйте отправить письмо. Не забудьте про правку с первого комментария.

Comment: --$boundary
        Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"$filename\"
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
        Content-Disposition: attachment;



дает файлы с расширением .pngContent-Transfer-Encoding-base64Content-Disposition-attachment

Comment: Добавьте точку с запятой вот так  Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"$filename\" ;

Comment: --$boundary
        Content-Type: image/jpeg; name=\"$filename\";
        Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
        Content-Disposition: attachment;

        $attachment";

получаю корректное расширение, но пишет что файл поврежден и не открывает его. "Fatal error reading PNG image file: Not a PNG file"

Answer (score 1):

Умно написано... Сначала получить данные, а потом делать проверку... Ваш код не безопасный и является уязвимым, вот приблизительно то что должно находится в Вашем файле после отправки запроса.

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    // Получаем данные и обрабатываем их
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
}
else
{
    //Вывод страницы 404 
}
```